# Isolate portion of line from log file, then print to screen

Tags: grep

If I have a file that updates a record count every 5 minutes, the output looks something like this:

`timestamp name of log file dataset record count 8600`

`timestamp name of log file dataset record count 8610`

How can I effectively isolate `dataset record count XXXX` and print just that string to screen?

Comment: from a file, or from a command?  Just that text `dataset record count (etc)` or only the matching (entire) lines?

Comment: Just that portion of the log file line. Not the entire line itself

Comment: Are you using an Operating System whose grep supports the `-o` flag? (GNU/Linux systems, mainly)

Comment: Rhel 7. I've attempted using `-o`, but admittedly I'm confused by the man page entry for it and may not be using it properly. Seems a bit convoluted to me.

Comment: Sorry, -o man page isn't confusing; -w is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, with awk:

```
awk 'match($0, "dataset record count [[:digit:]]+") { print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' input
```

or piped via:

```
command | awk 'match($0, "dataset record count [[:digit:]]+") { print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }'
```

Or with a grep that accepts `-o`:

```
grep -Eo 'dataset record count [[:digit:]]+' input
```

or piped:

```
command | grep -Eo 'dataset record count [[:digit:]]+'
```

Comment: I've tried `grep -Eo 'dataset [a-z A-Z 0-9]'` but I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: I needed to add the + to the end of the bracket